# ajax call only works when tablesorter is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I really don't know how to explain this.  I have a table and I am using tablesorter to make columns sortable.

at the end of each row i have a button that has a jquery listener to fire off an ajax call.  For debugging purposes, all that called script does is print_r($_POST).  This ajax call only works after I click on a column to sort table.  IF i don't,  i get no response from ajax call.  In firebug, if i dont click on column to sort, I get a red http:Post response, if i click on a table column, i get the response i would expect.

```
 //tablesorter call
 $('#pendingItems').tablesorter();

  //dialog setup
 $('#removeItem').dialog(
    {
            autoOpen:false,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: 
    {
            "Ok": function()
            {
                    //window.location.replace('items.php');
            }
    }
    });
 //listener for button click
 $('.removeItem').click (function()
 {
    var attrId = $(this).attr('id');
    var gid = attrId.split('_');
    var itemId = gid[1];
            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",  
                            url: "removeItems.php",
                            data: "itemId="+itemId,
                            success: function(result)
                            {
                                    alert('hi');
                                    $('#removeItem').html(result);
                                    $('#removeItem').dialog('open');
                            }
                    });

 });
```

and in the table.

```
  <input type='image' src='images/trashcan2.png' id='remove_" . $r['id'] . "' name='remove_" . $r['id'] . "' class='removeItem'>
```

where $r['id'] is a number.

in firebug:

looking at net tab. on failed attempt, the post goes to items.php (the original page). if i click on table column, and then the button, the post goes to the removeItems.php (the correct page)......

Comment: Check the class name in the button (removeGame), it is different than the selector of your onclick event handler (removeItem). If it was only an error when you post it an not in your code, try your ajax code without having attached the tablesorter plugin. If it works without it, perhaps you might want to change the way you are attaching the event handler to avoid collision with tablesorter code.

Comment: I removed tablesorter all together(the call in jquery as well as the link to the actual files. and get just red response from firebug....and yes, removeGame is typo, it is actually removeItem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (probably...) `tablesorter` is modifying the DOM, causing your bindings to disappear.

To see if that is the problem - and to solve it - just change:

```
$('.removeItem').click (function()
```

to:

```
$('.removeItem').on('click', function()
```

Note that `on()` requires jQuery 1.7+

Comment: no dice @jeroen.  I removed tablesorter all together(the call in jquery as well as the link to the actual files. and get just red response from firebug....

Comment: @bart2puck Check what exactly is happening in the console, the net-tab, etc. Just the colour `red` doesn't help much :-) Also check if the html is what you are expecting it to be.

Comment: in the net section: i see POST <<original Page>>.php  no errors in the net tab.  in the console tab i see POST:http://url/<<ajaxPage>>.php   no errors in the net tab

Comment: @bart2puck Do you have an online example?

Comment: its on a private server that I would have to move mountains to get public.

Comment: how can i get more detail in firebug console to see why its red?  I examined the details, and in good scenario, i get response.  in failed, i dont.  headers all are identical.

Comment: @bart2puck Don't now, you could try the Chrome Developers Tools to see if you get more information.

Comment: so looking at net tab.  on failed attempt, the post goes to items.php (the original page).   if i click on table column,  and then the button,  the post goes to the removeItem.php (the correct page)......

Comment: @bart2puck Is that all the javascript you have? I would start removing stuff (the modal dialog for example) to see what causes the problem.

Comment: yea, i am doing that and found the problem.  input type='button' works.  input type='image' does not.....

Comment: just have to figure out why now...shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: @bart2puck `type="image"` submits the form, so at the very least you would have to do `$('.removeItem').on('click', function(event) { event.preventDefault();` to make sure the form does not get submitted the normal way.

Comment: just found that same time you did.  Thanks for help.

Comment: @bart2puck Hmmmmm, still doesn't explain why it would work after sorting but if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Also in POSt type, data should be like:  data: {temId: itemId},

Answer (score 0):

So i found that input type image submits the form.  Adding return false; to the click event fixed the problem.